# Switch case failing to call recursively another function

Tags: javascript, function, recursion, switch-statement

I am trying to call recursively another function "cityname()" with switch case#1 and I am getting
"TypeError: cityname is not a function"
the purpose is to give users option to enter the City name again and again if the user requests.

Note: I have excluded the other cases which are working fine.

```
import axios from "axios";
import readlineSync from "readline-sync";

cityname()

function cityname(){
const apiKey = 'xyz';
var name = readlineSync.question(`Enter City Name:\n`);
return getWeatherData(name,apiKey)
})


function getWeatherData(cityname, apiKey) {
    axios.get(`https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=${cityname}&appid=${apiKey}`)
    .then((res)=>{
        let data = res.data
        var options = readlineSync.questionInt(`Select an option below for ${cityname}\n
        1. Change City\n
        0. Exit\n`)

        switch(options)
        {
        
        case 1: cityname();
        case 0: console.log('Exiting the program...');
        break;
        default:
        console.log('Invalid option. Please try again.');
        break;
         }
    })
}
```

Comment: @[Mohammed Naseer Ahmed](https://stackoverflow.com/users/22230268/mohammed-naseer-ahmed) change function ```getWeatherData(cityname, apiKey)``` argument's cityname to some different name. It shadows(conflicts) with function name. If this answers your question, kindly close it as it's just a very minor error.

Answer (score 0):

You just need to change your argument named `'cityname'` to something else, as it shadows (conflicts in your case) with the function with same name `cityname()`. I have renamed the argument `cityname` to `myCity`.
Here is the updated code of yours

```js
import axios from "axios";
import readlineSync from "readline-sync";

cityname()

function cityname(){
const apiKey = 'xyz';
var name = readlineSync.question(`Enter City Name:\n`);
return getWeatherData(name,apiKey)
})


function getWeatherData(myCity, apiKey) {
    axios.get(`https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=${myCity}&appid=${apiKey}`)
    .then((res)=>{
        let data = res.data
        var options = readlineSync.questionInt(`Select an option below for ${myCity}\n
        1. Change City\n
        0. Exit\n`)

        switch(options)
        {
        
        case 1: cityname();
        case 0: console.log('Exiting the program...');
        break;
        default:
        console.log('Invalid option. Please try again.');
        break;
         }
    })
}
```

Comment: "*I have renamed the argument cityname to cityName.*" - that doesn't make it any less confusing

Comment: @Bergi, what error you are facing after renaming the argument to cityName? Is it the same error?

Comment: No error, the code from your answer works. Just it still contains two badly chosen names.

Comment: @Bergi, It's not related to naming convention, the issue is that is'a conflict in function name and argument name. He is facing this issue because he is using the same name for the argument as well function.

Comment: If you aren't facing any error after changing the name, then it seems to resolve it. Hope you got it what I meant to say.

Comment: Anyways, updated cityName to myCity.